# How to 'Parse and Transform an Object into another Object with different "key/value" structure'

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, recursion

I'm using "jQuery Query Builder"(in UI) to generate a custom Object based on user inputs and I need to feed this Object as the input of the "json-rules-engine"(in Server) to generate a Result based on the conditions in the object. But the problem is Query Builder gives output in a different format and the Rules Engine takes the input in some other format.

I'm able to iterate through all the nodes of the Object and get the "keys/values" respectively. But I'm not able to use those "values" in order to generate a new Object with different structure.

```js
var object = {
  "condition": "OR",
  "rules": [{
      "condition": "AND",
      "rules": [{
          "field": "name",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": "romeo"
        },
        {
          "field": "category",
          "operator": "not_equal",
          "value": "books"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "condition": "AND",
      "rules": [{
          "field": "price",
          "operator": "greater_or_equal",
          "value": 100
        },
        {
          "field": "in_stock",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function printObj(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    var value = obj[key];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      printObj(value);
    } else {
      console.log(value);
    }
  }
}
printObj(object);
```

Currently I can iterate through all the nodes and read all the "key/value"s. But I need to transform this Object into something like the following:

Expected Output:

```js
{
  any: [{
    all: [{
      fact: 'name',
      operator: 'equal',
      value: "romeo"
    }, {
      fact: 'category',
      operator: 'not_equal',
      value: "books"
    }]
  }, {
    all: [{
      fact: 'price',
      operator: 'greater_or_equal',
      value: 100
    }, {
      fact: 'in_stock',
      operator: 'equal',
      value: 1
    }]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a quick stab at this. See my working example: https://jsfiddle.net/30m1z25r/

You were on the right track with your recursion function `printObj`.

The function I have created:

```
/**
 * Format a jQuery Query Builder object for json-rules-engine
 *
 * @param       {Object}    query       Pass the query builder object
 * @return  {Object}                    Formatted object
 */
function formatQuery(query) {
    var condition   = (query.condition || '').toLowerCase();
    var rules           = query.rules || [];
    var type            = condition === 'and' ? 'all' : 'any';

    if (condition) {
        // Create an empty object for appending values
        var build = {};

        // Create empty array for storing formatted children
        build[type] = [];

        // Loop through rules and append formatted objects
        for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
            var rule = rules[i];
            build[type].push( formatQuery(rule) );
        }

        // Return fully formatted object
        return build;
    }

    // If no condition, return self
    return query;
}
```

*This isn't fully tested so you might need to do some tweaking

Comment: Yes. It is working fine. Thank you for making it simple and clean.